# SQL Self Join and take a record by a condition on a third join

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I have a query where I'm doing a self join on TableA on 'Id1' and 'Id2'.  I then do an inner join on TableB.  The table with the self join as 2 keys (Id1,Id2).  I'm trying to get the records that do not match up with the Id in Table3.  Is it a condition that I need to add on the join?  Thanks!

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA t1
JOIN TableA t2 ON t1.Id1 = t2.Id2
JOIN TableB t3 ON t1.Id1 = t3.Id
```

EDIT :

```
SELECT *
FROM UCDetails ucd1
JOIN MS et ON ucd1.UKey = TRY_CAST(et.SubKey AS bigint)
JOIN dbo.UCDetails ucd2 ON ucd1.UKey = ucd2.ETTSubkey 
WHERE ucd1.ETTSubkey IS NULL
```

Sorry, I should of been more specific, so here is the query.  What I want is to take only the record from ucd1 or ucd2 where if the ucd1 ETTSubkey IS NULL and the 'UKey' DOES NOT match the 'et.Subkey'.  I can pull the records with this join but I only want to take the 'UCD' record where there isn't a match with the 'Subkey' on the et table.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What doesn't match up?  And why do you need a self join if you only care about `id1`?

Comment: Perhaps you actually want a `NOT EXISTS`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want rows where either id does not match in `tableB`, then use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from tableA a
where not exists (select 1
                  from tableB b
                  where b.id = a.id1
                 ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from tableB b
                  where b.id = a.id2
                 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the records that do not match up with the Id in
> Table3

If by match up you mean that `TableB`'s `Id` is equal to either `Id1` or `Id2` in `TableA`, then you only need a `LEFT` join that filters out the matching rows:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b
ON b.Id IN (a.Id1, a.Id2)
WHERE b.Id IS NULL
```